# Firefox duplicating large websocket messages when server takes time to receive the messages

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, browser, websocket

## What I'm trying to do

- I have a Javascript client (in browser) that sends 10 1mb arrays of data (this would normally be binary data from files but I tried to simplify as much as possible) to a websocket server
- The client sends all of the data as fast as it can in a normal `for` loop
- The server reads from the websocket connection, reading the data into memory and then does some processing on that data before moving on (in the go example, `time.Sleep` is used to represent "processing data", the Python version is already quite slow so I didn't add a sleep)

---

## Code to reproduce

### Client

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/');

ws.onopen = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Create a 1mb array filled with the value of `i`.
        const data = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024);
        for (let j = 0; j < 1024 * 1024; j++) {
            data[j] = i;
        }
        ws.send(data);
    }
};
```

### Servers (either one will reproduce issue)

Python:

```py
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket

class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):
    def handleMessage(self):
        print(self.data[0:10])
    def handleConnected(self):
        print(self.address, 'connected')
    def handleClose(self):
        print(self.address, 'closed')

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('127.0.0.1', 8080, SimpleEcho)
server.serveforever()
```

Golang:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func websocketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    upgrader := websocket.Upgrader{}
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    ws, _ := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    defer ws.Close()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        _, fileBytes, _ := ws.ReadMessage()
        fmt.Println(fileBytes[0:10])
        // Represents taking 1 second to process uploaded data.
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", websocketHandler).Methods("GET")
    _ = http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", r)
}
```

---

## Desired Behavior

All of the data from the javascript client should end up on the go server, with the
server printing out a received array for each number, here's an example server log which
shows the first 10 bytes of each message received:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
[6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
[7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]
[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]
[9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
```

This is exactly what I want, each different array was received only once.

---

## What actually happens

is that some of the data is read by the server, and then the server reads the same data
again from the websocket, instead of new data.

In the below server log, you can see that it works fine until the data array containing
"5"s gets received 4 times in a row, and then jumps to receiving the "8"'s:

```
Serving at http://127.0.0.1:8080
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]
```

This only happens if the Javascript is run in Firefox (v82.0 64-bit), **the code works as
intended if I run it in Chrome**.

I have also tested in Firefox Developer edition (83.0b4) and the same bug happens.

---

## Weird things that stop the issue

If the `time.Sleep` call is commented out in the go server code, the duplication does
not happen.

The python version is inherently slow to process the requests without sleeping (hence
no call to sleep to represent processing data), so there is no way to test on the
Python server if receiving the websocket messages faster stops the duplication.

This leads me to believe that the issue may be timing related?

The duplication also does not happen if, in the Javascript, the 2 `1024 * 1024`
statements are replaced with a variable that is pre-calculated, for example

```js
const ws = // websocket
const dataSize = 1024 * 1024;

// rest of code up to:

        const data = new Uint8Array(dataSize);
        for (let j = 0; j < dataSize; j++) {
```

---

I have no idea why any of this is happening, i'm starting to suspect that this is a bug
within Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

It looks like this is definitely a Firefox bug and there's already a bugzilla report on it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1673340)

Comment: You might want to use a network analysis tool like Wireshark to verify what's actually being sent over the socket.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and it looks like a FF82 bug. I also ran into another large-message issue where when "per message deflate" compression is turned on in the server, FF82 sends broken/nonsensical payloads. For the record I used WireShark and verified that it's FF sending the duplicate/busted payloads. The Developer Tools websocket message inspector says one thing, and FF82 does another, it seems.

Comment: @Marius ok, thanks for letting me know. I've opened a bug report on bugzilla so I guess I'll wait for an official response on that